# GUI for Standard ML?

Tags: user-interface, binding, sml, ml, graphical-programming

I started learning Standard ML recently out of curiosity. So what I know is that is has an efficient compiler (MLton) which allows us to freely use abstractions without worrying about performance.

It would be perfect if I could do some GUI programming with Standard ML, too. Is there anything like Gtk, Qt, or WxWidgets binding for Standard ML?

Thank you very much.

Comment: You'd have better luck with OCaml, which is a more widely used ML variant (outside of academia).  If you're willing to make a larger leap away from SML, Haskell has excellent GUI toolkits too.

Comment: Oh thanks. I already learned Haskell, though not much with the GUI stuff. I was curious about SML just in case I needed performance that could compare with C, lol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's [a paper](http://www.usenix.org/event/usenix04/tech/freenix/full_papers/larsen/larsen.pdf) describing the [mGTK](http://mgtk.sourceforge.net/) project, which is a Standard ML binding to GTK. There are also a couple of [interfaces to OpenGL](http://mlton.org/OpenGL), although this is more 2 and 3D graphics-oriented rather than specifically a GUI toolkit. [eXene](http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~stough/eXene/index.html) is a toolkit for X Windows. [sml_tk](http://www.informatik.uni-bremen.de/~cxl/sml_tk/) is an interface to Tk.

Comment: Thanks. I also did some googling and found the mGTK and SML-Gtk projects, but it looked like they haven't been updated for a long time :(

Answer (score 3):

There are bindings for foreign toolkits, but the [eXene](http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~stough/eXene/index.html) toolkit was designed to be native for SML and to exploit the features of Concurrent ML.  I used it years ago and found it a very smooth fit for the language and a pleasure to use.  But it does not have the ginormous library of components that you find in the more widely used toolkits.

Answer (score 0):

[Giraffe Library](http://giraffelibrary.org/) provides SML bindings to libraries that support [GObject Introspection](https://gi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), which includes GTK.  At the time of writing, bindings are available for the GTK 3 stack.  Although the cairo graphics library does not support GObject Introspection, Giraffe Library provides bindings to some cairo functions.

Although SML has a very precise definition, the definition does not include an FFI, and there is considerable variation between compilers.  At the time of writing, Giraffe Library supports only the FFIs of [MLton](http://mlton.org/) and [Poly/ML](https://www.polyml.org/).